# Extensibility Model - Extending UserPrincipal

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, directoryservices

My code:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(
  ContextType.Domain, "domain controller", "ou=foo,dc=bar,dc=com");
var userSearcher =
  new PrincipalSearcher(new ActiveDirectoryUserPrincipal(context));
var results = userSearcher.FindAll();
Console.WriteLine(results.Count()); // outputs 2182

var regularUserSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context));
var results2 = regularUserSearcher.FindAll();
Console.WriteLine(results2.Count()); // outputs 1579

var computerSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new ComputerPrincipal(context));
var results3 = computerSearcher.FindAll();
Console.WriteLine(results3.Count()); // outputs 603


[DirectoryObjectClass("user")]
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("cn")]
public class ActiveDirectoryUserPrincipal : UserPrincipal
{
  ...
}
```

My custom principal returns computers **and** users. Anyone have a good suggestion on the best way to fix this? I know I could do this:

```
DirectoryProperty("objectCategory")]
public string ObjectCategory
{
    get
    {
        var result = this.ExtensionGet("objectCategory");
        if (result == null || result.Length != 1)
            return null;
        else
            return (string)result[0];
    }
    set
    {
        this.ExtensionSet("objectCategory", value);
    }
}
```

and change the search to

```
var userSearchTemplate = new ActiveDirectoryUserPrincipal(context);
userSearchTemplate.ObjectCategory = "person";
var userSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userSearchTemplate);
var results = userSearcher.FindAll();
```

but it seems more like a hack than a solution...